# Why will this dataframe not populate?

Tags: r

I am using the R programming language.  I am trying to fill a dataframe with a For Loop.  The dataframe will not populate.  Can someone take a look at my code and tell me what is going wrong?  I am using data that has compiled a list of films and their earnings throughout time.  Below is the code that I am using.  The dataframe stays filled with "NA" for all cells.

Thanks!

```
weeks = unique(movieDB$releaseDate)
weeks

finalDB = data.frame(matrix(NA,length(weeks),3))
finalDB

colnames(finalDB) = c("date","releaseLogBoxOfficeDiff","laterLogBoxOfficeDiff")
    finalDB


# Populate the Data Frame # 
for(i in 1:nrow(movieDB)){
row = finalDB$date == movieDB$releaseDate[i]
films = subset(movieDB, releaseDate[i] == movieDB$releaseDate &     releaseRank <=2)
    if(nrow(films) == 2) {
       releaseWeek1 = films$releaseWeekEarnings[films$releaseRank == 1]
       releaseWeek2 = films$releaseWeekEarnings[films$releaseRank == 2]
       laterWeek1   = films$subsequentEarnings[films$releaseRank == 1]
       laterWeek2   = films$subsequentEarnings[films$releaseRank == 2]
       finalDB$releaseLogBoxOfficeDiff[row] = log(releaseWeek1) -     log(releaseWeek2)
     }
   }
```

Sample Data:

```
Title   releaseWeekEarnings subsequentEarnings  releaseDate releaseRank
1   \xc1 Deriva NA  0   NA  1
2   \xe0 la folie... pas du tout    91630   632364  2/14/03 4
3   \xe0 L'Int\xe9rieur NA  0   NA  2
4   A Mulher Invis\xedvel   NA  0   NA  3
5   A.K.: The Making of Ran NA  0   NA  4
6   Aage Se Right   NA  0   NA  5
7   Aaja Nachle 257500  144599  11/30/07    2
8   Aap Kaa Surroor NA  0   NA  6
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Comment: 1 \xc1 Deriva NA NA NA 1
2 2 \xe0 la folie... pas du tout 91630 632364 2/14/03 4
3 3 \xe0 L'Int\xe9rieur NA NA NA 2
4 4 A Mulher Invis\xedvel NA NA NA 3
5 5 A.K.: The Making of Ran NA NA NA 4
6 6 Aage Se Right NA NA NA 5
7 7 Aaja Nachle 257500 144599 11/30/07 2
8 8 Aap Kaa Surroor NA NA NA 6
9 9 Abandon 5064077 3715821 10/18/02 2
10 10 The Abandoned 782000 184524 2/23/07 5
11 11 ABC Africa 1857 1674 5/3/02 11
12 12 ABCD 83372 NA 11/30/01 4
13 13 Abduction: The Megumi Yokota Story 5034 8019 11/24/06 7

Comment: Title releaseWeekEarnings subsequentEarnings releaseDate releaseRank
1 \xc1 Deriva NA 0 NA 1
2 \xe0 la folie... pas du tout 91630 632364 2/14/03 4
3 \xe0 L'Int\xe9rieur NA 0 NA 2
4 A Mulher Invis\xedvel NA 0 NA 3
5 A.K.: The Making of Ran NA 0 NA 4
6 Aage Se Right NA 0 NA 5

Comment: Does the second comment help? I copied and pasted from an excel CSV.  As is the format. 5 columns as follows - title, releaseWeekEarnings, subsequentEarnings, releaseDate, releaseRank

Comment: dont post the data in the comments.. really?

Comment: What are you trying to do when you write `row = finalDB$date == movieDB$releaseDate[i]`

Comment: Adrian - I am trying to make the vector "finalDB$date" be the same as "movieDB$releaseDate"

Comment: Okay, I have been sleeping ;-) Does my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Look at what `movieDB` actually contains. Do `head(movieDB)` and `str(movieDB)`. Does the data look as you expect it to?

Here is what it looks like with your sample data:

```
> head(movieDB)
  Number                     Title releaseWeekEarnings subsequentEarnings releaseDate releaseRank
1      1                  À Deriva                  NA                  0        <NA>           1
2      2 à la folie... pas du tout               91630             632364     2/14/03           4
3      3             à L'Intérieur                  NA                  0        <NA>           2
4      4        A Mulher Invisível                  NA                  0        <NA>           3
5      5   A.K.: The Making of Ran                  NA                  0        <NA>           4
6      6             Aage Se Right                  NA                  0        <NA>           5

> str(movieDB)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Number             : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 $ Title              : Factor w/ 8 levels "À Deriva","à L'Intérieur",..: 1 3 2 4 5 6 7 8
 $ releaseWeekEarnings: int  NA 91630 NA NA NA NA 257500 NA
 $ subsequentEarnings : int  0 632364 0 0 0 0 144599 0
 $ releaseDate        : Factor w/ 2 levels "11/30/07","2/14/03": NA 2 NA NA NA NA 1 NA
 $ releaseRank        : int  1 4 2 3 4 5 2 6
>
```

I do not have your original data and do not know how your read it into R, but I had to clean up your sample data a bit to be able to read it:

1. Your data contains six columns but only five column names. The first column is the row number. Add something like `Number` or `ID` before `Title` in the header line (first line), or delete that column.
2. Enclose the movie titles in quotes so R does not see spaces in titles as separators.

   Look at `?read.table` and make sure your quotes are different from characters in `Title`. E.g. if your titles contain apostrophes as in `L'Intérieur`, you cannot use single quotes. You can define other characters as quotes with `read.table(..., quote="-")`. Quotes must be ASCII, so look at your data in Excel to understand which characters are available.
3. Delete multibyte characters such as `\xe0` from the titles or export them in an encoding that your system can deal with.

   You should be able to take care of all of the above in the settings when you export from Excel.

After that cleanup, I read the data in to R:

```
movieDB <- read.table(textConnection("
Number Title releaseWeekEarnings subsequentEarnings releaseDate releaseRank
1 \"À Deriva\" NA 0 NA 1
2 \"à la folie... pas du tout\" 91630 632364 2/14/03 4
3 \"à L'Intérieur\" NA 0 NA 2
4 \"A Mulher Invisível\" NA 0 NA 3
5 \"A.K.: The Making of Ran\" NA 0 NA 4
6 \"Aage Se Right\" NA 0 NA 5
7 \"Aaja Nachle\" 257500 144599 11/30/07 2
8 \"Aap Kaa Surroor\" NA 0 NA 6
"), header=TRUE)
```

And now your code works, but since the relevant columns contain missing data – **only the second movie is listed with a release Date** –, all calculations using those missing values must result in `NA` as well:

```
> weeks = unique(movieDB$releaseDate)
> weeks
[1] <NA>     2/14/03  11/30/07
Levels: 11/30/07 2/14/03
> 
> finalDB = data.frame(matrix(NA,length(weeks),3))
> finalDB
  X1 X2 X3
1 NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA
> 
> colnames(finalDB) = c("date","releaseLogBoxOfficeDiff","laterLogBoxOfficeDiff")
>     finalDB
  date releaseLogBoxOfficeDiff laterLogBoxOfficeDiff
1   NA                      NA                    NA
2   NA                      NA                    NA
3   NA                      NA                    NA
> 
> 
> # Populate the Data Frame # 
> for(i in 1:nrow(movieDB)){
+ row = finalDB$date == movieDB$releaseDate[i]
+ films = subset(movieDB, releaseDate[i] == movieDB$releaseDate &     releaseRank <=2)
+     if(nrow(films) == 2) {
+        releaseWeek1 = films$releaseWeekEarnings[films$releaseRank == 1]
+        releaseWeek2 = films$releaseWeekEarnings[films$releaseRank == 2]
+        laterWeek1   = films$subsequentEarnings[films$releaseRank == 1]
+        laterWeek2   = films$subsequentEarnings[films$releaseRank == 2]
+        finalDB$releaseLogBoxOfficeDiff[row] = log(releaseWeek1) -     log(releaseWeek2)
+      }
+    }
> finalDB
  date releaseLogBoxOfficeDiff laterLogBoxOfficeDiff
1   NA                      NA                    NA
2   NA                      NA                    NA
3   NA                      NA                    NA
```